# Iterators in Method call / Functional Equivalence / Best Practise

Tags: c++, iterator

Quick question about how something is evaluated by the compiler. In the below code I'm wondering if what I've written is a good idea, or whether I should be more explicit.

```
constexpr auto Checksum = [](const std::vector<uint8_t>& values) -> std::array<uint8_t, 6> {
  std::vector<uint8_t> data{ 0x03, 0x03, 0x00, 0x17, 0x13 };
  data.insert(data.end(), values.begin(), values.end());
  data.resize(data.size() + 6);
  uint32_t c = 1;
  for (const auto v_i : data)
  {
    uint8_t c0 = c >> 25;
    c = ((c & 0x1ffffff) << 5) ^ v_i;
    if (c0 & 1)
      c ^= 0x3b6a57b2;
    if (c0 & 2)
      c ^= 0x26508e6d;
    if (c0 & 4)
      c ^= 0x1ea119fa;
    if (c0 & 8)
      c ^= 0x3d4233dd;
    if (c0 & 16)
      c ^= 0x2a1462b3;
  }
  c ^= 0x2bc830a3;
  std::array<uint8_t, 6> ret;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    ret[i] = (c >> (5 * (5 - i))) & 31;
  return ret;
};

std::vector<uint8_t> data = ConvertBits();
data.insert(data.end(), Checksum(data).begin(), Checksum(data).end());   //  <------------ What is happening here?
```

Obviously the arguments to *.insert()* are guaranteed to be fully constructed before being used, but are the iterators working on an invisible temporary?  Should I be more explicit and do:

```
std::array<uint8_t, 6> temp = Checksum(data);
data.insert(data.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

Is the above code and using the iterators directly in the *.insert()* method functionally equivalent to one another?

Comment: `data.insert(data.end(), Checksum(data).begin(), Checksum(data).end());` -- This is not valid.  If it worked, you were lucky (or unlucky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constexpr auto Checksum = [](const std::vector<uint8_t>& values) -> std::array<uint8_t, 6> 
{
    //...
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> ret;
    //...
    return ret;
}
//...
data.insert(data.end(), Checksum(data).begin(), Checksum(data).end());
```

The `data.insert` invokes undefined behavior, due to `Checksum(data).begin()` and `Checksum(data).end()` being iterators to two totally different `std::array` containers.

The return semantics of `Checksum` is by-value, and you're returning a `std::array<uint8_t, 6>`.  If you were returning a reference to the same `std::array<uint8_t, 6>`, then the line would be viable.

On the other hand, this code:

```
std::array<uint8_t, 6> temp = Checksum(data);
data.insert(data.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

is safe to use, since `temp` is the same `std::array` object.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought...  that each iterator would be pointing to two different temporaries and that the Checksum() function would be invoked twice.  Hence the question purpose.  The understanding I was looking for though was... given the above, there could be the compiler understanding that a single temporary could be used and both iterators acted upon that single temporary.  I guess that does involve some understanding that the call to the lambda should only happen once.  You need some shared knowledge between arguments.

Comment: I know the arguments may be evaluated in different orders, so I guess it makes sense, but compilers do some clever stuff and there does seem to be enough information for the deduction that both these iterators could operate on the same const container.